# Volvo s40 Oil Pressure light

Tags: volvo, oil-leak

My fiance was driving our S40 to work this morning and saw a bit of smoke rolling from under the hood, she decided to let the smoke dissipate then limp the car home.

On the return trip the car kicked on the Oil Pressure light so she parked in the nearest lot. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm going to be getting into with this fix?

Comment: There is not much information here to go on.

Comment: Pretty certain it's an oil leak on the passenger side of the engine, I don't have much more info at this point. Hopefully more tonight.

Comment: okay, got to look at it last night. Oil level is fine, little splatter on the inside of the timing belt cover but that may be old. 

It blew the return hose from the coolant reservoir off, and spit sludge down the side of the radiator. no leak apparent aside from that. 

It also has a pin hole in the fuel line leading to the fuel pressure regulator, that sprayed across the top of the block. No idea why the oil pressure light would come on though from those 2 issues.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that you might for sure be dealing with is an oil leak.  Possibly higher up such that it is dripping on the exhaust or the side of the engine.

Comment: Remember to check the dipstick on a cool engine for accurate readings.